# Laravel Has Many Through Only brings first record

Tags: php, laravel

Well that is my problem.

This is the public function in my model

```
public function traerDesc(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\modeloDescripcionVehiculos', 'App\modeloVehiculos', 'idDescripcion', 'id', 'idVehiculo');
    }
```

This is the controller call

```
    $data = [

                'venta' => modeloAccion::where('accion', 'venta')->with('traerVehiculo', 'traerUsuario', 'traerCliente', 'traerTransaccion', 'traerVenta', 'traerDesc')->get(),
     ];

   return view('modulos.general.informes')->with($data);
```

This is my table in the blade file

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="myTable">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-center">Vehiculo vendido</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Precio de compra</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Precio de venta</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Ganancia %</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Usuario</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Cliente</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Fecha venta</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach($venta as $ventas)
                                <tr class="text-center">
                                    @foreach($ventas->traerDesc as $descripcion)
                                        <td>{{$descripcion->marca}}</td>
                                    @endforeach
                                    <td>{{$ventas->traerVehiculo->precioCompra}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$ventas->traerVehiculo->precioVenta}}</td>
                                    <td>asd</td>
                                    <td>{{$ventas->traerUsuario->nombre.' '.$ventas->traerUsuario->apellidoPaterno.' '.$ventas->traerUsuario->apellidoMaterno}}</td>
                                    <td>asd</td>
                                    <td>{{date('d-m-Y', strtotime($ventas->traerVenta->fechaVenta))}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

This is my table accion. As you can see . It has 3 rows where `accion = venta` and all of them has the same info in all the tables. But it only brings the first row rejecting the others

[image: Database]

And the view shows only 1 `marca` that would be like brand in english.

[image]

Hope can make myself clear enough. Thank you

Comment: Just a small comment but in the future it might be handier to just code everything in plain english as it might be a bit easier to quickly comprehend for people that want to help out. Cheers!

Comment: You said that there are 3 records and all of the three `accions` (actions) are `venta` (sale) ?

Comment: I think im going to reformulate my question .

Comment: The with method performs some kind of join within the models. Are you sure those three rows have a relationship with the methods you've defined: 'traerVehiculo', 'traerUsuario', 'traerCliente', 'traerTransaccion', 'traerVenta', 'traerDesc' ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will help, but you use eager loading method `with` wrong way.
Right using is:

```
Model::with(relations)->where(condition)->get();
```

Or

```
Model::where(condition)->get()->load(relations);
```